# Problems calling a Function - "not defined"

Tags: python

as the topics asks: How do you import/reference another already written (exterior) program within a main program?

if I have a file named Squares.py with this inside of it:

```
def squares(x):
     for i in x:
         return i*i
squares(x)
```

...how do I tell an umbrella program to reference it?  Do I use an import command at the top of the overhead program?  How would I write it?

Comment: Use "from Squares import squares" to import squares from the Squares.py file

Comment: Inventing your own jargon (exterior program, umbrella program, overhead program) makes your question hard to understand

Comment: Sorry, as I learn the appropriate jargon, I will try to use it in the future.

Comment: Is this answer too easy, or frustrating?  Really need some help.  Never claimed to be an expert.

Comment: The problem I am having is that you are trying to cover too much with one question. To answer your question about importing directly it's easier if you already have a `squares` function that actually works and can be imported first. Don't worry about being a beginner - just take smaller steps and ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to `import Squares` because `x` isn't defined on the last line

```
def squares(x):
     for i in x:
         return i*i
squares([23])
```

You need to fix that problem first

The function itself probably doesn't do what you want. Is `x` supposed to be a `list` or an `int` or something else?

Supposing you fix those problems, you should isolate the bottom part with a test

```
def squares(x):
     for i in x:
         return i*i
if __name__ == "__main__":
    squares([23])
```

This will prevent `squares` being called implicitly when you import the module

You'll then be able to simply use:

```
import Squares
result = Squares.square([23])
```

or

```
from Squares import square
result = square([23])
```

Comment: can you please walk me through the first problem you mentioned?

Comment: I really appreciate all of the help.  I'll add this as my accepted answer, but I still can't seem to get this right.  I have a more involved topic over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000097/need-help-calling-a-function-into-a-different-file-python where I hope to get this straightened out.

Answer (score 0):

The `squares.py` module you show is broken -- on being either run or imported it will die with an exception, because it calls `squares` with a never-defined global variable `x`.

Assuming you had a module that is **not** broken, and it lives in a directory listed on `sys.path`, then

```
import squares
```

at the top of another Python file will import `squares` as a module in the other Python file.

Comment: I'm getting: name 'x' is not defined... I'm guessing this is what you mean by broken.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @evambivalence, if you want to call `squares(x)`, you **have** to know what `x` is supposed to be, no?!  So **tell** Python what it is by e.g `x=[23]` just before that call to `squares(x)`.  (That function `squares` despite the misleading name only returns the single square of the first item in its list argument, of course -- that's another issue).

Comment: I'm trying to follow your advice, but not succeeding.  I placed a `x=[23]` below the definition but above the `for i in x` line.  I then called to that program in the overhead program with `squareslist = squares(x)` where x is a list I'm using.